# Javascript class member

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, react-native, redux

I'm looking at https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/Actions.js#L36
Where it says:

```
class Action {
  currentRouter: ?BaseRouter;
  constructor {
  ...
```

From what I can tell `: ?BaseRouter;` gets removed because it's flow syntax. But what is `currentRouter`? And how is the value defined? I don't see it defined anywhere in the code and in the bottom they create a new instance of the class and export it.

Comment: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=currentRouter : BaseRouter.js line 132.

Answer (score 0):

That pattern is following a factory method.  In the action class they are defining a method (in a local variable) called `currentRouter` and getting the contents of that method from the `?BaseRouter` service (which is defined elsewhere and injected).